# how audioRecord retrieve data with a specified sampling rate

Tags: java, android, fft, android-audiorecord

my experiment is like this:
first, I use matlab to create a specified wave file with a rate of 44100, which means any fragment lasting 1s contains 44100 elements and these elements are presented as double.
then, I use smartphone's microphone to retrieve the wave. And the sampling rate is 44100, in order to restore the wave.
But, audioRecord store the data as byte, while what i want is double. Converting from byte to double sounds reasonable, I still confused that sampling rate 44100 means the audioRecord should record 44100 bytes in 1s or 44100*4 bytes, since double contains 4 bytes?
Other experiment i have committed:
using recording software to retrieve wave and store in .wav
read the .wav by matlab's wavread and by java respectively.
To 1s, we get 44100 elements, and list below:
-0.00164794921875
1.52587890625E-4
2.74658203125E-4
-0.003326416015625
0.001373291015625
-4.2724609375E-4
0.00445556640625
9.1552734375E-5
-9.1552734375E-4
7.62939453125E-4
-0.003997802734375
9.46044921875E-4
-0.00103759765625
0.002471923828125
0.001922607421875
-0.00250244140625
8.85009765625E-4
-0.0032958984375
8.23974609375E-4
8.23974609375E-4
anyone know how many elements the audioRecord will retrieve in 1s with the sampling rate of 44100?

Answer (score 3):

The default for AudioRecord is to return 16-bits per channel for each sample (`ENCODING_PCM_16BIT`).

Now there are two read overloads that let you specify either a short[] (16 bits) or a byte[] (8 bits) buffer.

```
int read(short[] audioData, int offsetInShorts, int sizeInShorts)
int read(byte[] audioData, int offsetInBytes, int sizeInBytes)
```

So a 1 second mono buffer (1 channel) should have a `short[]` buffer of length 44100. Stereo (2 channels) would have 88200, etc...

I would avoid using the `byte[]` buffer unless you had set the AudioRecord format to `ENCODING_PCM_8BIT` for some reason (it is not guaranteed to be supported by all devices).

Now if you want to convert those short values to doubles you have to realize that the `double` values you record in matlab are `double-precision normalized samples` which are normalized from `[-1 to 1]` while the `short` values are going to be from `[-32768 to 32767]` so you would have to write a conversion function instead of just trying to cast the numbers from a short to a double.